# Using "window-shopped" online

Tags: word-usage

> I window-shopped for shoes online.

Is it correct to use the word window-shop if it is online?

Comment: If you're window-shopping on one of those sites where a (real or bot) salesperson appears in a pop-up saying *Hi! Can I help you?*, at least you get the chance to be a real smart-ass when you reply *No thanks. I'm just [web] **browsing**!*

Answer (score 2):

[*Window shopping*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+window-shopping) means 'just looking at things for sale, without intending to buy anything'. Since the important part is the intent (idle browsing) rather than the physical method (looking in through shop windows), I see nothing wrong with using it to describe the same activity online.

If anything, the phrase holds up a bit better than other idiomatic phrases affected by the march of technology ('pen pal', for instance, or 'broken record'), because there is still a 'window' involved - the one on your computer screen.

Comment: I like your reference to the computer "window"!

Answer (score 0):

While 'window-shopping' would convey the message, I may prefer telling ...

> I just *browsed* for shoes *OR* I was just *browsing* for shoes

'browse' will take care of being 'online'.

To my surprise, 'browse' **also** means -*just [looking at the product and not buying it](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=browse)!*